# Get the dynamic ID from the response page in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In my application after a successful log in am getting a table and in that table I am trying to access an URL which is a table data element. But To click the URL in Jmeter I need the dynamic code which is
`/wps/myportal/trial-home/trial/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi_Z3DPC2cDB0NLLycXAw8DYPcfIMczQwNzAz1wwkpiAJKG-AAjgZA_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` (Please refer the table data below).

This value changed according the user logged in and will be not constant. But this value `OraUpgPrgm` will be constant for all users.

```
 <td>OraUpgPrgm
</td>
<td><a href="#"
onclick="navigate('/wps/myportal/trial-home/trial/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi_Z3DPC2cDB0NLLycXAw8DYPcfIMczQwNzAz1wwkpiAJKG-AAjgZA_VFgJc7ujh4m5j4GBhamFoYGno4eoeZmwS5GBo7GUAV4zCjIjTDIdFRUBACr47ms/dz/d5/L0lJSklKSUtJS1VLVUtVUW9ncFFwUXBSQ2lDbEVLSUtVUW9ncFJDaUNsQ2xDbEVLSUtVUSEvNEZNREFBQUFBR0JBQUFBRUNEQVFJVUtEQ2d3NFVPQWlnSUlVSkVoUklVYUpHZ3hJTUVKRml3NHNPQ0ZqeDRDZUFoRHhFaUpJaVFoRXlaQ21RcFV5VkdtUm9ReWRPZ3pvTUlkQS80TmxHUW9ZNWxIR3QyRXRwTlJUVTAxRE5ic0piV2FqbXBwcWVhM1lTMkMxSXRic0piSmFtV3QyRXRpdFNyVzdDV3pXcDFxRGFrMnQyRXRsdFRhQSEvWjZfT0NWSThCMUEwOEpCRDBJMVJGTVJBNjEwUDQvWjdfT0NWSThCMUEwMDlGMjBJM0xPR0pDSDEwQzMvZ2xvYmFsL2h0dHA6JTAlMG15dHJpYWxzLmNvbSUwcHJwL3Nwb25zb3JJZC8xMzk3L04vT3JhVXBnU3Bucl9wcm9kL3Byb2dyYW1JZC8xMDkxL09yYVVwZ1ByZ20vY29udGV4dC9TUFQvZWNsaW5pY2FsU3BvbnNvcklEL01ZUzAxMTE2L2VjbGluaWNhbFRyaWFsSUQvTVlUMDAwMTUyNjMvdHJpYWxJZC81NzIzL1kvT3JhVXBnVHJsL2VjbGluaWNhbFByb2dyYW1JRC9NWVAwMDAwNzA5/',
'N','N','Y');"><span class="trialDesc">OraUpgTrl</span></a> <span
onclick="showTrialApplications('5723','true')">
<a class="infoPopup" aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-0"> <img
src="/wps/mycontenthandler/dav/fs-type1/themes/pi-theme/css/mytrials/themeImages/info-small.png"></a>
</span></td>
```

Table Data:
[image]

How to retrieve this value ?

Note: I cannot use the onclick because there are other td which have similar `onclick` value with similar alpha numeric value. Want the very specific value for the td which have `OraUpgUTrl`,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be choosing either of `CSS Selector` or `X-Path` to handle this, as you have given only part of the DOM difficult to provide you the exact `Xpath or CSS Selector`.

But the following regex work for me as well,

```
OraUpgPrgm\s*</td>\s*<td>\s*<a\s*href="#"\s*onclick="navigate\('(.+?)',
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the page is generating the dynamic url from the server response you can use Css Selector extractor or Regex Extractor to fetch the value

I have tried with RegEx with the example give above - it's working fine for me

`onclick="navigate\('([^\s]+)',`

[image]

Result
[image]

If that is generated using a client side javascript - you need to implement the logic using JSR223

Comment: In that case - you can extend the boundary to match it 

`onclick="navigate\('([^\s]+)',\s'N','N','Y'\);"><span class="trialDesc">OraUpgTrl</span>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for this, the relevant regular expression would be something like

```
onclick="navigate\('(.+?)'
```

[image]

Another option is using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor), it would be easier as you just need to provide "left" and "right" boundaries

[image]

If Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor matches > 1 element you will need to use i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to fetch `onlcick` attribute value from the "interesting" `<a>` tag first and then apply the above to the resulting JMeter Variable

Comment: Try reading the last stanza of the answer